# Hibernate generates many select statements for JPQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpql

I wrote an JPQL to fetch a list of `ProductOrderU` entities for the given customer id, but I noticed that many select statements are generated, whereas I would expect only one. For example (I use Oracle):

```sql
select * from product_order where order_id in (select order_id from orders where customer_id in (1));
```

Hibernate generates:

```
Hibernate: select productord0_.order_id as order_id1_8_, productord0_.product_id as product_id2_8_, productord0_.amount_of_ordered_products as amount_of_ordered_3_8_ from product_order productord0_ cross join orders orderu1_ where productord0_.order_id=orderu1_.order_id and orderu1_.customer_id=?
Hibernate: select orderu0_.order_id as order_id1_6_0_, orderu0_.cost_of_delivery as cost_of_delivery2_6_0_, orderu0_.cost_of_products as cost_of_products3_6_0_, orderu0_.customer_id as customer_id5_6_0_, orderu0_.delivery_id as delivery_id6_6_0_, orderu0_.final_cost as final_cost4_6_0_ from orders orderu0_ where orderu0_.order_id=?
Hibernate: select productu0_.product_id as product_id1_7_0_, productu0_.amount_in_stock as amount_in_stock2_7_0_, productu0_.category_id as category_id11_7_0_, productu0_.description as description3_7_0_, productu0_.product_name as product_name4_7_0_, productu0_.product_price as product_price5_7_0_, productu0_.production_year as production_year6_7_0_, productu0_.promotion_id as promotion_id12_7_0_, productu0_."size" as size7_7_0_, productu0_.sold_amount as sold_amount8_7_0_, productu0_.vendor as vendor9_7_0_, productu0_.weight as weight10_7_0_ from product productu0_ where productu0_.product_id=?
Hibernate: select complaints0_.order_id as order_id1_2_0_, complaints0_.complaint_id as complaint_id2_2_0_, complaintu1_.complaint_id as complaint_id1_1_1_, complaintu1_.complaint_time as complaint_time2_1_1_, complaintu1_.content as content3_1_1_, complaintu1_.handling_time as handling_time4_1_1_ from complaints_for_orders complaints0_ inner join complaint complaintu1_ on complaints0_.complaint_id=complaintu1_.complaint_id where complaints0_.order_id=?
Hibernate: select customeru0_.customer_id as customer_id1_3_0_, customeru0_.city as city2_3_0_, customeru0_.email as email3_3_0_, customeru0_.first_name as first_name4_3_0_, customeru0_.flat_number as flat_number5_3_0_, customeru0_.house_number as house_number6_3_0_, customeru0_.password as password7_3_0_, customeru0_.phone_number as phone_number8_3_0_, customeru0_.postal_code as postal_code9_3_0_, customeru0_.street as street10_3_0_, customeru0_.surname as surname11_3_0_ from customer customeru0_ where customeru0_.customer_id=?
Hibernate: select deliveryu0_.delivery_id as delivery_id1_4_0_, deliveryu0_.delivery_company_id as delivery_company_i4_4_0_, deliveryu0_.delivery_time as delivery_time2_4_0_, deliveryu0_.price as price3_4_0_, deliveryu0_.promotion_id as promotion_id5_4_0_ from delivery deliveryu0_ where deliveryu0_.delivery_id=?
Hibernate: select deliveryco0_.delivery_company_id as delivery_company_i1_5_0_, deliveryco0_.delivery_company_name as delivery_company_n2_5_0_ from delivery_company deliveryco0_ where deliveryco0_.delivery_company_id=?
Hibernate: select categoryu0_.category_id as category_id1_0_0_, categoryu0_.category_name as category_name2_0_0_, categoryu0_.parent_category_id as parent_category_id3_0_0_, categoryu0_.promotion_id as promotion_id4_0_0_ from category categoryu0_ where categoryu0_.category_id=?
Hibernate: select categoryu0_.category_id as category_id1_0_0_, categoryu0_.category_name as category_name2_0_0_, categoryu0_.parent_category_id as parent_category_id3_0_0_, categoryu0_.promotion_id as promotion_id4_0_0_ from category categoryu0_ where categoryu0_.category_id=?
```

The question is why? Something is bad with the query or so many select statements just have to generated.

Method for fetching:

```java
@Transactional
public List<ProductOrderU> fetchProductOrders(Long customerId)
{
   return entityManager.createQuery("select po from ProductOrderU po where po.order.customer.customerId = :customerId", ProductOrderU.class)
                .setParameter("customerId", customerId).getResultList();
}
```

`ProductOrderU` is a parent entity for several others:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_order")
@Setter
@Getter
public class ProductOrderU
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProductOrderIdU productOrderId = new ProductOrderIdU();

    private Long amountOfOrderedProducts;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("productId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
    private ProductU product;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("orderId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private OrderU order;
}
```

And the relationships:
[image: Relationship]

Comment: can you use inner join like this and see `select * from product_order p,orders  o where p.order_id =o.order_id and o.customer_id in (1);` subquery can create many queries internally.

Comment: The generated SQL seems fairly resaonnable in the sense of loading a whole `ProductOrder` object graph. JPA implementations usually have a way to control wether or not the relationships (one/many to one/many) get loaded at the same time as their entities, e.g. joins, inner joins, fetch types, fetch plans... the configuration of which is hard to tune (sometimes you want eager fetching, other times you do not). But all in all, the SQL you showed is reasonnable **if** the (near) full object graph is requested.

Comment: @GPI full object graph loading, from the ```ProductOrder``` point of view is desired, that is ```Product```, ```Category```, ```Order``` and so on. However I don't understand why hibernate generates several select statements for that. Can't he fetch those entities with only one select? If you count, he makes 9 selects, object graph contains 9 entities, so he performs one select per entity I guess.

Comment: OK, so your question is not so much the why but the how. You should check out fetch strategies, e.g. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching